Why is に used in ｢楽しみにしています」instead of を
I know construct of を + する meaning to do something to an object, but i never heard of に + する. Why is it not 楽しみをしています. Meaning roughly "I'm doing some looking forward to"

You can understand 楽しみにしています as それを楽しみにしています. It is literally understood as made it as something to look forward to. This is the typical ～を～にする construction asked many times here.
